# Qt - open dialog when action triggered multiple times

Tags: qt, qt-signals, qaction

I want a notice dialog to come up when an action has been triggered multiple times consecutively (so basically a bit like how StickyKeys is enabled). I understand that I can basically do `connect(this->trigger, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(onTrigger()))` for detecting a single trigger, but how could I detect when it happens 10 times?

Thanks.

P.S - how could I do a "don't show this message again" QCheckBox?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your slot in the following way:

```
void MyClass::onTrigger()
{
    static int count = 0;
    if (count++ == 10) {
        // show the dialog here
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing the return type from the signature.

Comment: Please reset counter.

Comment: @user2672165, I don't see requirement to show dialog on **each** 10 clicks or so.

Comment: I would be careful about using static variables in class methods. They are shared across all instances of that class.

Answer (score 0):

You would need an external counter for this as the connect method, or QObject cannot do this for you out-of-box. I would write this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), m_cnt(0)
{
    ...
    // Removed the needless this usage
    connect(trigger, SIGNAL(triggered()), SLOT(onTrigger()));
    ...
}

void MyClass::onTrigger()
{
    if (m_cnt++ == 10) {
        m_dialog.show();
        // or: m_dialog.exec();
    }
}
```